# How to send static (Cached Data) will be refreshed around every 2 hours to Operators in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Singleton Class(ConfigurationUtil) in my main Method to load the static data and then using it inside my operator to process the events, but I am getting Nullpointer Exception. I can see that instance is not getting initialized in the Main class. So I tried initializing the ConfigurationUtil in AsyncDataStreamOperator is got initizalized but after loading same NullPointer exception is coming on accessing the instance data:

My Main Class where I am instantiating the Class and defining operators.

```
ConfigurationUtil.getInstance().loadConfigurations(properties);

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Event> enrichedStream = AsyncDataStream
                .unorderedWait(eventStream, new AsyncExternalCalls(properties), 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 3)
                .name("External Enrichment")
                .uid("ExternalEnrichment");
```

This is inside my ConfigurationUtil

```
    private static ConfigurationUtil instance;
    private ConfigurationDetails configurationDetails;

    public void loadConfigurations(Properties properties)  {
        // loading configuration data from db
        loadExternalEnrichCache(false,properties);
        loadDataEnrichCache(false,properties);
        loadDataEnrichUrlMangementCache(properties);
        loadErrorConfigCache(properties);
        saveProperties(properties);
        LOG.warn("configurationDetails: {}", this.configurationDetails);
    }

    public static ConfigurationUtil getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            LOG.warn("Creating ConfigurationUtil Object");
            instance = new ConfigurationUtil();
        }

        return instance;
    }
```

I am using that cache inside my AsyncDataStream Operator.

```
        ExternalEnrichmentDetailsCache extDetails = ConfigurationUtil.getInstance().getConfigurationDetails().getExternalEnrichmentDetails().get(event.getEventId());
        JSONArray extEnrichment = extDetails.getExternal();
```

Error Logs

```
2021-06-07 11:47:02,912 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher  - Shutting down the shard consumer threads of subtask 0 ...
2021-06-07 11:47:02,914 WARN  com.telstra.eov.enrichment.AsyncExternalCalls                 - Async External Enrichment - Close
2021-06-07 11:47:02,915 INFO  org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher  - Shutting down the shard consumer threads of subtask 0 ...
2021-06-07 11:47:02,916 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Kinesis Source -> Event Stream  -> External Enrichment -> Update data enrichment details (1/1) (36afadaa2b9493386df71c09e46688b4) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hide.hide.hide.ExternalEnrichment.processElement(ExternalEnrichment.java:110)
    at com.hide.hide.hide.ExternalEnrichment.processElement(ExternalEnrichment.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator.processElement(ProcessOperator.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:579)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:554)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:534)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:718)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:696)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51)
    at com.telstra.eov.enrichment.JsonToEventStream.processElement(JsonToEventStream.java:49)
    at com.telstra.eov.enrichment.JsonToEventStream.processElement(JsonToEventStream.java:25)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator.processElement(ProcessOperator.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:579)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:554)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:534)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:718)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:696)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher.emitRecordAndUpdateState(KinesisDataFetcher.java:776)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher.access$000(KinesisDataFetcher.java:92)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher$AsyncKinesisRecordEmitter.emit(KinesisDataFetcher.java:273)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher$SyncKinesisRecordEmitter$1.put(KinesisDataFetcher.java:288)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher$SyncKinesisRecordEmitter$1.put(KinesisDataFetcher.java:285)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.KinesisDataFetcher.emitRecordAndUpdateState(KinesisDataFetcher.java:760)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.ShardConsumer.deserializeRecordForCollectionAndUpdateState(ShardConsumer.java:371)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.ShardConsumer.run(ShardConsumer.java:258)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-06-07 11:47:02,919 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Freeing task resources for Source: Kinesis Source -> Event Stream  -> External Enrichment -> Update data enrichment details (1/1) (36afadaa2b9493386df71c09e46688b4).
```

I see the close function is getting called before the NullPointer. Not sure if that is issue? Any help will be much appreciated. Let me know if any further information is required.

Answer (score 2):

Flink distributes operators across multiple JVMs/servers, so using statics to "share" data doesn't work. Please see the [Broadcast State Pattern](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/) page for how Flink supports sharing data.